# My screen got colorless and internet doesn't work properly

Tags: factory-reset, screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

All is explained in the title. I'm an Android noobie using Samsung S5 and this problem is at hand for around an hour. Should I factory reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You activated Ultra power saving mode. Turn it off to fix the issue.